# Form validation out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, cs50

I'm working on an assignment for the CS50 course and I'm new to Jquery/Ajax. In one of the forms, a registration form, I'm checking the username entered into a text field against existing users. I have the code make GET requests to a Flask/Python backend, which then queries the DB and returns a Json (true/false for user already exists yes or no).

I've disabled to submit button by default. Only if the user types in an username that is unique, the submit button is enabled. Otherwise, an error message is displayed and the submit button remains disabled. This I check "live" with a keyup function.

Code works just fine, except when I type in an existing username real fast. Then somehow, the submit button is enabled instead of disabled.  It's almost like the browser is still catching up with the GET request to the backend and therefore registers the incomplete name and does not respond correctly to the latest value entered as the username.

For example, when I type in "John" (an existing user), In can see in the (Flask) console that the JSONs are not returned in the order I typed, e.g. "J", "Jo", "Joh", "John". But instead the order of the returned Jsons is e.g. "Jo", "J", "John", "Joh". Which in that case causes the submit button the be enabled incorrectly, since the current value of field "Username" is "John" which is an existing user.

I've pasted a snippet of my JS code below, could you please give me some pointers?

```
    <script>
    (function() {
    $( "#username" ).keyup(function(event) {
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        $.ajax({
                url: "/check",
                data: {username: username},
                dataType: "json",
                }).done(
                        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                            {
                                if (data == true)
                                {
                                    $('#usernameExists').removeClass('collapse');
                                    document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $('#usernameExists').addClass('collapse');
                                    document.getElementById("register").disabled = false;

                                }
                            }
                );
    });
    })();
    </script>
```

Comment: since the GET requests are all asynchronous, there's no guarantee of the order in which they will complete - `$.ajax` returns a Promise-like object, which you could chain

Comment: Thanks. But how would one then handle a form field validation like this? I've tried disabled async, but this seems to be not supported by Jquery anymore.

Comment: as mentioned, $.ajax returns a Promise, so, you can chain the requests in such a way that they perform *in order* - something like https://pastebin.com/ExC7ZjXC

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps. I added my comment to early. Your example is clear, I'll look further into Promises.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I edited the first comment while you were responding to it :p

Comment: No worries I'm still new to this website. :) I think I can't accept upvote/mark your response as accepted since it's a comment? Hope you don't mind

Comment: All good, I wasn't going to post it as an answer because I'm not very good with jquery, so the code may not be the best solution with jquery

Comment: Also, you might want to consider adding this: on each keyup you could wait a little before making a call to the server. Say 1 second (not sure what delay yields the best user experience). If the customer types in another character within that time window, reset the timer and wait for another 1 second. Keep doing this until at some point one second passes with no new keys pressed. Then you can call the server. This will greatly reduce the load on the server. Combine this with promises as suggested and you'll have yourself a pretty robust solution : ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `onkeyup`? Let the user complete their thought.  As you've discovered it executes the script for each letter. This will cause innacurate results, for example if there is an existing user "JohnDoe", then poor "John" will never be able to register.

Have a look at [`onchange` in MDN doc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)